# How to wait for async task to finish its work then execute the next statements without freezing the UI

Tags: android

```
        RetrieveBusStoppage retrieveBusStoppage = new RetrieveBusStoppage();
        retrieveBusStoppage.executeOnExecutor(retrieveBusStoppage.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,classes[i], Integer.toString(i));
        //retrieveBusStoppage.execute(classes[i], Integer.toString(i));  // Retrieving stoppages of bus one by one

        for(int j=0;j<busstoppage.get(i).size();j++) {

            if (source.equalsIgnoreCase(busstoppage.get(i).get(j).toString())) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"UP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                result = "up";
                break;
            }
            if (destination.equalsIgnoreCase(busstoppage.get(i).get(j).toString())) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                result = "down";
                break;
            }
        }
```

I want retrieveBusStoppage  to complete fully then execute the for loop because in retrieveBusStoppage  I am retrieving the value of busstoppage from database. But in this it is executing the for loop without completing the retrieveBusStoppage.execute call. That's why the value of bustoppage is showing Zero, since the value from database is not saved in it.

Comment: "How to wait for async task to finish its work then execute the next statements without freezing the UI" -- by definition, that is not possible. Move your `for` loop into `onPostExecute()` of the `AsyncTask`, as that is why `onPostExecute()` exists: to let you update the UI after having done the I/O on a background thread.

Comment: There are many solutions.One way is by moving your for loop into OnPostexecute().Second way is when you execute the AsyncTask you can call Thread.sleep() for mainthread and resume the main thread in onPostExecute().Third way is to use synchronized(retrivebusstoppage){   }

Comment: @akhil-rao . 1.Will the second one freeze the UI ? 2. Can you explain the 3rd one in details .Thank you

Comment: There is a yet another way to do that, and it seems to be a very logical one: 1) move the toasts from the loop to onPostExecute() 2) move the loop itself to doInBackground() method. 3) Then pass the "result" as a parameter using async task pattern. So you will avoid the loop in the main (UI) thread.

Comment: Don't call sleep in the main thread, it will freeze the UI.